# t test in python on a frequency table

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

If I have two lists of numbers `X` and `Y`, I can run a t-test on them using `scipy.stats.ttest_ind(X,Y)`. So far so good. If instead of `X` and `Y`, I have frequency counts; is there a pythonic way to run an efficient t test or do I have to "manually" calculate the original vectors?

**Edit (frequency count):** If `X = [1,0,3,0,1,3,2]` then the corresponding frequency count is:

```
+---+---+
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
+---+---+
```

where the first column is the value and the second is its corresponding count/frequency.

Comment: What do you mean frequency counts? Do you have two vectors of frequency counts? Do you have two proportions?

Comment: You might look at the statsmodels package: search "frequency" on [this page](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/stats.html) for some options on weighted t-tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rv_discrete from scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html) to generate data according to the distribution marked by your frequencies.

Using the example of frequency counts you provide in your edit, you would generate your random variable like this,

```
import scipy.stats as stats

x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
freq = [2, 2, 1, 2]
total = sum(freq)
p = [i/total for i in freq]
custm = stats.rv_discrete(name='custm', values=(x, p))
```

where you take into account that the vector of probabilities `p` has to sum 1.

And then you can generate data from your distribution very easily,

```
In [7]:
custm.rvs(size=7)

Out[7]:
array([2, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is indeed nice, but I'm not sure that it actually helps. I'm looking for an efficient pythonic way to run t-test on two vectors that are given as frequencies counts.